# EXIF DateTimeOriginal format - disable seconds recording

Tags: jpeg, exif

the EXIF DateTimeOriginal format is YYYY:MM:DD (HH:MM:SS) per its [specification](http://www.w3.org/2003/12/exif/). I don't want to records the seconds from the time. I want my format to be YYYY:MM:DD (HH:MM).

How I can achieve this, regardless the OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) lets you read and write EXIF data.  You can use it to extract the timestamp, set the seconds value to zero and write it back.

ExifTool works on Windows, Linux and Mac.  You'll need to write a script or program to manipulate the timestamp, but you can use your script or programming language of choice.

Comment: I don't want to set the seconds to 00. I want not to record them at all, thus :SS filed will disappear.

Comment: The EXIF date/time fields use ISO standard date strings, which require the seconds field as far as I know.  If you were to figure out a way toactually remove the seconds field, it may cause problems for other programs that try to parse it.  You could certainly try using Exiftool to write the timestamp without the seconds field. I suspect it will either complain or it will set seconds to zero.